# How can I input a filename and download the file in Python?

Tags: python, automation

I have data base of file. I'm writing a program to ask the user to input file name and using that input to find the file, download it,make a folder locally and save the file..which module in Python should be used?

Comment: `selenium` or `bs4` or maybe `requests`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Can be as small as this:

```
import requests

my_filename = input('Please enter a filename:')
my_url = 'http://www.somedomain/'
r = requests.get(my_url + my_filename, allow_redirects=True)
with open(my_filename, 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, do you have the database online?
If so I would suggest you the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module, very pythonic and fast.
Another great module based on requests is [robobrowser](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html).

Eventually, you may need [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML or XML data.

I would avoid using selenium because it's designed for web-testing, it needs a browser and its webdriver and it's pretty slow. It doesn't fit your needs at all.

Finally, to interact with the database I'd use [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Here a sample:

```py
from requests import Session
import os

filename = input()

with Session() as session:
    url = f'http://www.domain.example/{filename}'
    try:
        response = session.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print('File not existing')
    download_path = f'C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\Downloads\\your application'
    os.makedirs(dowload_path, exist_ok=True)
    with open(os.path.join(download_path, filename), mode='wb') as dbfile:
        dbfile.write(response.content)
```